# (Doctrine2-Symfony2) Return foreign keys with findAll()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, findall

I am returning an object with the following code :

```
$myVariable = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainBundle:TheEntity')->findAll();
```

My question would be : Is there a way to also return the foreign keys with a similar function ?

Thank you.

Comment: `$myVariable` contains all the `TheEntity` stored in your database. I'm not sure to understand what you want..

Comment: If your foreign keys are set inside doctrine properly (ManyToOne, ManyToMany etc.), you can just get the entity through the getter of your Entity.
You're working with classes, not arrays or something.

Comment: @Koalabaerchen Though you can work with flattened arrays (and you should to prevent high memory usage) using a Query Builder and `getArrayResult()`

Comment: @sjagr No, no, no. Please don't tell people stuff like that. If you have a load problems because you're handling objects, not the objects are the problem.

Comment: @Koalabaerchen [Avoiding object hydration and why](http://labs.octivi.com/mastering-symfony2-performance-doctrine/)

Answer (score 0):

By default Doctrine will fetch an associated entity when you call it so you can just use something like `$myAssociatedEntity = $myEntities->getMyAssociatedEntity()`. That is called `lazy loading` and will lead to many small requests so it is usually best suited for a quick prototyping. Better practice would be to write your own repository method with a JOIN clause so you get everything in one bigger request.